# Can java JSON parser be configured to allow empty values?

Tags: java, json, gson

The following json string is not being parsed because "orgId" : , does not specify an empty value. Is there any way to get the json parser to accept this or is this always invalid?

200 (OK)
    Content-Type: application/json

```
{
    "orgId": ,
    "orgName": "Department of JSON",
    "orgProfile": {
    "publicName": "",
    "numHits": 29,
},
    "orgDescript": {
      "someOrgDescription": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: No; that is not valid JSON.

Comment: That's very akin to asking "Is there a way I can get my compiler to just ignore syntax errors?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's syntactically invalid JSON. No way around it. If you want to omit a value, there are two options:

```
{
    "orgId": null,
    "orgName": "Department of JSON",
    "orgProfile": {
        "publicName": "",
        "numHits": 29
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "orgName": "Department of JSON",
    "orgProfile": {
        "publicName": "",
        "numHits": 29
    }
}
```

See http://www.json.org and/or [run your JSON through a validator.](http://jsonlint.com/)